# Add up all possibilities in a list, with two variables

Tags: python, list, addition

I am trying to make a program in python that will accept a user's input and check if it is a Kaprekar number.
I'm still a beginner, and have been having a lot of issues, but my main issue now that I can't seem to solve is how I would add up all possibilities in a list, with only two variables. I'm probably not explaining it very well so here is an example:

I have a list that contains the numbers
`['2', '0', '2', '5']`.
How would I make python do `2 + 025`, `20 + 25` and `202 + 5`?

It would be inside an if else statement, and as soon as it would equal the user inputted number, it would stop.

([Here](http://pastebin.com/Kg9bQq47) is what the entire code looks like if it helps- where it currently says `if  1 == 0:`, it should be adding them up.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you start with

```
a = ['2', '0', '2', '5']
```

Then you can run

```
>>>  [(a[: i], a[i: ]) for i in range(1, len(a))]
[(['2'], ['0', '2', '5']), (['2', '0'], ['2', '5']), (['2', '0', '2'], ['5'])]
```

to obtain all the possible contiguous splits.

If you want to process it further, you can change it to numbers via

```
>>> [(int(''.join(a[: i])), int(''.join(a[i: ]))) for i in range(1, len(a))]
[(2, 25), (20, 25), (202, 5)]
```

or add them up

```
>>> [int(''.join(a[: i])) + int(''.join(a[i: ])) for i in range(1, len(a))]
[27, 45, 207]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you can write an expression to determine whether a number, N, is a Krapekar number more concisely.

```
>>> N=45
>>> digits=str(N**2)
>>> Krapekar=any([N==int(digits[:_])+int(digits[_:]) for _ in range(1,len(digits))])
>>> Krapekar
True
```